# In scrapy do calls to crawler.engine.crawl() bypass the throttling mechanism?

Tags: scrapy

To give some background, I'm writing a spider that listens on a RabbitMQ topic for new URLs to spider. When it pulls a URL from the queue it adds it to the crawl queue by calling crawler.engine.crawl(request). Ive noticed that if i drop 200 urls onto the queue (all for the same domain) I sometimes get timeouts, however this doesn't happen if i add the 200 urls via the start_urls property.

So I'm wondering if the normal throttling mechanisms (concurrent requests per domain, delay etc) apply when adding urls via crawler.engine.crawl()?

Here is a small code sample:

```
    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def read(self, queue_object):
        # pull a url from the RabbitMQ topic
        ch,method,properties,body = yield queue_object.get()
        if body:
            req = Request(url=body)
            log.msg('Scheduling ' + body + ' for crawl')
            self.crawler.engine.crawl(req, spider=self)
        yield ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't bypass the `DownloaderMiddlewares`or the `Downloader`. They go to the `Scheduler` directly bypassing the `SpiderMiddlewares`.

[Source](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/core/engine.py#L167)

IMO you should use a [`SpiderMiddleware`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/master/topics/spider-middleware.html) using `process_start_requests` to override your `spider.start_requests`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not actually bypassing start_requests I have a separate task.LoopingCall() which basically polls the rabbit queue and calls crawler.engine.crawl()